# how to check whether the inputed url is valid or not?

Tags: jquery, regex, url

I want to check whether the inputed url is valid or not.

here is my code

```
var regExpURL = /((http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)|)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
var websiteURL = $("#txtotherwebsite").val();
if(!regExpURL.test(websiteURL))
{
   $("#errorwebsite")[0].innerHTML = "Invalid website name.";
   $("#txtotherwebsite").removeClass("successTextBox").addClass("errorTextBox");
   return false;
}
else
{
    $("#errorwebsite")[0].innerHTML = "";
    $("#txtotherwebsite").removeClass("errorTextBox").addClass("successTextBox");
    return true;
}
return false;
```

but when i am using this it goes in else only. regExpURL.test(websiteURL) always returns true.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following Regex:

```
(?<Protocol>\w+):\/\/(?<Domain>[\w@][\w.:@]+)\/?[\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,]*
```

To test it go to: http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx

Put in the source textbox:

```
http://www.usgs.gov
http://www.acl.lanl.gov/URI/archive/uri-archive.index.html
ftp://@host.com/
ftp://host.com/
ftp://foo:@host.com/
ftp://myname@host.dom/%2Fetc/motd
file://vms.host.edu/disk$user/my/notes/note12345.txt
prospero://host.dom//pros/name
```

Put on the Regex textbox

```
(?<Protocol>\w+):\/\/(?<Domain>[\w@][\w.:@]+)\/?[\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,]*
```

It will match all of the above URL's

Hope it may help you